# datatable attribute infoFiltered:("_TOTAL_" == 0) ? " " : " (_MAX_ row)" ternary operator is not working correctly in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

The datatable plugin have a option like infoFiltered: " ". I used the ternary operator like `infoFiltered:("_TOTAL_" == 0) ? " " : " (_MAX_ row)"`. When i search something that data is not similar to any rows in the datatable,so zero results will be display.That time *TOTAL* value should be 0. So the above ternary operator should be true but that is always false.

Can i use the ternary operator in that place?
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a good question. `language.infoFiltered` does not support ternarys. Either way it would not do any difference since it is only referenced once - `infoFiltered` is not a dynamic value but a proprietary string "expression" for dataTables only. Of course you could use a function, as

```js
language: {
    infoFiltered: getFilter()
}
```

but this is also only called once, even before the dataTable has finished its initialisation. So the only workaround is to use the [**`infoCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback). I am not completely sure what you really want to display, but here is an example that will produce "*No matches found*" instead of the default "*Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries filtered from 57 total records*" :

```js
infoCallback: function(settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
   if (total == 0) return "No matches found";
   return 'Showing '+total+' to '+end+' of '+total+' entries';
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zj77rLtg/**

Comment: This one is working perfectly.
Thank you. @davidkonrad

Comment: howto show the the "infocallback" while filtering the data? @davidkonard

Comment: @kalles - what do you mean by "while filtering the data", as "filtered out of .."? If `max` is different from `total`, then you now the table is filtered.

Comment: filtering means searching.
search the row in the searching bar

Comment: `infoCallback` is called _every_ time the table is redrawn, so each time the user is filtering, `infoCallback` is triggered too. You can check if `max` and `total` is different to know some filtering is going on.

Comment: for example in the gmail i type in the searchbar kalles means that will give the mail belogs to kalles.